# How to safely define HTMLCollectionOf Elements in typescript with react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js, tslint

I am working on to create a d3 line chart with react and typescript and referring to https://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/e3b8b7c2ca4787f77d78f58d41c3da91 to achieve the mouse over functionality.

At one point we have to get the line element  and check the total path length of line.

```
const linesElement: any =  document.getElementsByClassName("line");

let beginning = 0,
        end = linesElement[i].getTotalLength(),
        target = null;

    while (true){
      target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
      pos = linesElement[i].getPointAtLength(target);
      if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
          break;
      }
      if (pos.x > mouse[0])      end = target;
      else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
      else break; //position found
    }
```

When I declare type as `any` I am getting `Type declaration of 'any' loses type-safety. Consider replacing it with a more precise type.tslint(no-any).`

When I declare type as `HTMLCollectionOf<Element>` I am getting the below error.

```
TS2339: Property 'getTotalLength' does not exist on type 'Element'.
TS2339: Property 'getPointAtLength' does not exist on type 'Element'
```

We do have a type restriction of using "any". So would like to know what is the better way to define lines

Answer (score 3):

[`getTotalLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength) function is defined only on SVG and is absent on normal `Element` interfaces. This is why this type error is happening.

What you can do here is to check if the element is an instance of `SVGPathElement`:

```
if(linesElement[i] instanceof SVGPathElement) {
  end = linesElement[i].getTotalLength();
}
```

Comment: Still I am seeing the type errors.  I even tried to declare the type as `HTMLCollectionOf<SVGPathElement>` and got `TS2322: Type 'HTMLCollectionOf<Element>' is not assignable to type 'HTMLCollectionOf<SVGPathElement>'` type error

Comment: You cannot declare it as a Type as `document.getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollectionOf<Element>`, this is already defined. you would have to instance check it like in the answer or cast it

Comment: I tried to instance check just like in the answer but still i am seeing the type errors `TS2339: Property 'getTotalLength' does not exist on type 'Element'.
TS2339: Property 'getPointAtLength' does not exist on type 'Element`

Comment: I don't know what you are going wrong unless you edit the code in question, but [here is a stackblitz reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-svg-element?file=index.ts) of how you should be.